# NHibernate (3.3.1) LINQ - Select() called more than once per object

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I have written a LINQ extension method simplified to the following:

```
public static class NHibernateSelectWithoutProxies
{
    public static IQueryable<T> SelectWithoutProxies<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) where T : new()
    {
        return query.Select<T, T>(x => Transform<T>(x));            
    }

    private static T Transform<T>(T source) where T : new()
    {
        return source;  // Simplified                                           
    }
}
```

There are 2 records being selected from the database. However, "Transform(source)" is called 3 times, 2 of which on the same "source".

(Note: after the query is executed and ToList() is called, the list contains 2 records. It seems that NHibernate LINQ ignores non-unique objects returned by the Select).

This behavior is only happening when the query has a Fetch, for example:

```
var groups = repository.Get()
                       .FetchMany(x => x.Members)
                       .Where(...)
                       .SelectWithoutProxies()
                       .ToList<ContactGroup>();
```

Will result in groups.Count == 2 and **three** calls to Transform.

However:

```
var groups = repository.Get()
                       .Where(...)
                       .SelectWithoutProxies()
                       .ToList<ContactGroup>();
```

Will result in groups.Count == 2 and **two** calls to Transform.

It seems to me as bug, but I may be missing something. Is this the expected behavior?